# Civievent custom data field duplicate fields in Edit

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

I encountered a strange situation.  I have added a custom data group in a participation record called "Emergency Contact"  with 2 fields and while this appeared ok in View of the participant records, there would be 2 such group displayed when i click Edit.  Entering only 1 of these 2 group will retain the values, the other group wouldn't.  Any idea how this happened and how it can be resolved?

WordPress: 5.0.4 CIVICRM: 5.10.4 Ubuntu

Comment: Could you add some screenshots?  Also, a lot has happened since 5.10.4 - I'd upgrade before investigating much further.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the custom field is configured to use for Participants entity with Event name/event type/role set to any.

Solution for fix:

1. Upgrade CiviCRM to 5.15 or 5.16 because i can't replicate the bug anymore on latest version of CiviCRM.
2. Change the custom field config to use only Participants as entity instead Participants(Event Name), Participants(Event Type) or Participants(Roles).

[image]

Thanks

Pradeep